# c++, stl map of pointers to functions vectors

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector, function-pointers

i seem to have some problem in creating a structure defined as the topic.

My objective is to create a sort of event handler, (it doesn't matter if it's good or bad programming,or if it is not multithread: for the moment is just for practice).

My idea is then to create a vector of pointers to functions, and place this vector in a map,where the key is a string.

i must be doing something conceptually wrong, because i get some strange errors:
My code is as following (errors are at the end):

```
.h file
//ptr to function
typedef int (*pt2Function)(void*);
typedef std::vector<pt2Function> fPtrVector;

class eventDispatcher
{

public:
    //stuff 
    void addListener(std::string,pt2Function);

protected:
    //stuff
     std::map<std::string,fPtrVector> _listeners;
};
```

and here is the cpp:

```
.cpp file

void eventDispatcher::addListener(std::string eventName ,pt2Function function)
{
  std::map<std::string,fPtrVector>::iterator it;

  it=this->_listeners.find(eventName);
  if(it != this->_listeners.end())
  {
//do something
  }
  else 
  {
    std::vector<pt2Function> tmp;
    tmp.insert(function);  // here occurs error 1

    this->_listeners.insert(eventName,tmp);  // here occurs error 2
    std::cout<<"cnt: "<< this->_listeners.count(); 
  }
```

}

The errors i get are:

```
1)  no matching function for call to 'std::vector <int (*)(void*), std::allocator<int (*)(void*)> >::insert(int (*&)(void*))'

2)  no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<int (*)(void*), std::allocator<int (*)(void*)> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<int (*)(void*), std::allocator<int (*)(void*)> > > > >::insert(std::string&, std::vector<int (*)(void*), std::allocator<int (*)(void*)> >&)'
```

Comment: I feel so dumb... thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check a reference to [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) you see that it takes two arguments, an iterator and the value. To just add a value use e.g [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) instead.

For the map, you can use `_listeners[eventName] = tmp;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

No variation of [`std::vector::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) takes a single argument: all take an iterator indicating the position to which the new element(s) must be inserted before. Use [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to add `function` instead.

[`std::map::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) has several variations, but the one you are attempting to use takes the [`value_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) of the `map`, which is defined as:

```
value_type  std::pair<const Key, T>
```

in your case the `value_type` is a `std::pair<std::string, fPtrVector>`:

```
this->_listeners.insert(std::pair(eventName,tmp));
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The `insert()` method of `std::vector` works by specifying a position using an iterator. For your case, you can use `push_back()`.

2) Use `insert(std::make_pair(eventName, tmp))` and that will create the required value type by the map.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are looking for `std::vector::push_back` ([see the documentation for `std::vector` here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)).
2. You are looking for `std::map::operator []` ([see the documentation for `std::map` here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)).